# Simple Architecture for just JSP, Servlet and Beans

Tags: java, architecture

I'm trying to develop a simple "homework submission system" with Java. I'm working on it as a practice for java web development but it is also goint to be used by my students. I read many stackoverflow threads and decided to use just JSP, Servlet and Beans and not to use any enterprise solution, framework etc. Because this is a learning trail and I'm planning to use that technologies after understanding this part first. I have read necessary chapters from Head First JSPs and CoreServlets.

What I'm looking for is a simple architecture(I'm not sure that this is the right word) that I can go with. Or a sample application like Pet Store but just uses pure JSP/Servlet/Bean stuff as I mentioned above.

Note: I already read a bunch of MVC tutorials that include one JSP, one Servlet and one Bean but when it comes to a whole application they are not satisfying.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Deliberately avoiding frameworks is just self-abuse. You're just making extra work for yourself, and your end result will not be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you propose makes sense for really small websites, as soon as you start getting bigger then you start reimplementing a lot of the functionality the is implemented in the web frameworks.

[Here is a good example](http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/JSPMVC.pdf) of doing what you request without a Framework.

Comment: Thanks this was somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Servlets and JSP Pages Best Practices](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/servlets-jsp-140445.html) by Qusay H. Mahmoud can be useful. In the last part of the article a simple MVC Model 2 architecture is showed where JSPs, Servlets and Beans are the View, the Controller and the Model, respectively.

If that's not enough, you can search any MVC implementation proposal with JSPs and Servlets on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Follow javapassion tutorialis by Sang Shin
Here is the link that you might be interested in -

[Build "HelloWeb" sample application](http://www.javapassion.com/handsonlabs/netbeanswebapp2/#Exercise_0)

Comment: Thanks but these are not what I'm looking for. I already did read a lot of tutorials including many book chapters.